# How to get clicked element id using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to get the HTML element ID, but it shows me "null".

Can you help plz.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1 id="Test">Just for test purposes</h1>
        <script>
        window.addEventListener('click', (e) => {

        let text = e.currentTarget.document.documentElement.getAttribute("id");

        alert(text);    
        })
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/id

Comment: You're accessing the ID properly, but you're using the wrong element– [`documentElement` refers to the root node of the page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/documentElement) (e.g. `<html>`), which has no ID attribute. That's why you're getting `null` here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### **Use `e.target.id`**

The `id` is readily available in the click event target, so it's unnecessary to use any method like `getAttribute()`. Simply accessing `e.target.id` works fine:

```
window.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
   let text = e.target.id;
   alert(text);    
})
```